# Is it a problem to leave a sprinkler line through concrete shed footing?

Tags: concrete, foundation, sprinkler-system

I'm in the process of getting an attached shed built in my house (due to HOA restrictions). They seem to be very competent. The contractor is subcontracting the concrete foundation pouring.

They have just dug the footing, pre-pour. I have noticed that a water line for the sprinkler system is going to go right through two sides of it and skim the front wall. I have asked about it and they said it should be fine running through the foundation.

I'm not terribly worried about the foundation itself from this. But it seems like it might be a concern from a servicing perspective, not moving the line. They will be redirecting the sump line though.

Does this sound right to you guys? Just want to double check.

Here is what it currently looks like:
[image]

Comment: This is a lawn sprinkler line, right?

Comment: run a 2" pipe from one side of the foundation to the other side of  the foundation .... pull the irrigation pipe through the 2" pipe .... use just a short piece of 2" pipe for the white pipe against the house

Comment: It is for a lawn sprinkler. This line feeds several sprinkler heads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People put flexible pipes inside concrete all the time (this is how heated floors are made)

you should space it away from the floor and trench mesh so that it does not become a conduit for moisture (from the soil) and oxygen to attack the reinforcing steel

If you have more of that line and some elbows now would be a good time to move it. But if you're feeling lazy it doesn't look particularly hard to replace the under-slab section with an external loop at a later date. if needed.

Comment: I ended up having the line moved around the shed entirely. It wasn't too costly.

Answer (score 0):

Know would be a good time to move it. Ya i would not want that.  What about the other pipe ,close to house? No extra holes in the foundation. And easy to repair.

Comment: The one close to the house is for the sump pump. That is getting moved. Really just turned to the side to come out of the side of the new structure.

Comment: I'm debating it. Moving it will be a pain in the ass for sure. Though, if anything, the section under the foundation may be safer from the elements. I'm concerned that contact with the foundation might encourage freezing. I guess if I have to repair it I will just route around it then.

Comment: You've offered an opinion with no explanation or supporting evidence. That's not particularly valuable to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Reroute that line out from under the foundation before you pour. If it would leak, it would soak the soil and soften it. This could cause the foundation to sink and get out of level. Sprinkler piping is prone to leaking.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a concern even if the pipe was outside the foundation, unless it was _way_ outside it?

Comment: A leak under the slab takes much longer to detect. I think putting the line 18" outside the foundation would make the effect of a leak negligible.

Answer (score -1):

Is it the green pipe in that photo? If so, that pipe is not deep enough in my opinion anyway. I would have that entire sprinkler pipe re-done to a proper depth, so whether or not you leave it there to be encased in the concrete becomes irrelevant.

Comment: The green line is the sprinkler line. It is a semi flexible material. I'm not going to pay to have the whole system redug. It came with the house this way and has been fine so far. I will fix things as they break. I'm in the Kansas City area. It just doesn't get that cold here anymore. I doubt freezing would be more than an inch deep.

Comment: @Patrick According to https://www.hammerpedia.com/missouri-frost-line/, frost depth in the Kansas City area is between 25 and 30 inches. You need to drain that sprinkler line in the fall. I suspect J. Raefield's recommendation to bury it deeper was not about frost, but about accidental damage from yardwork, gardening, and kids.

Comment: There's no answer to the actual question here.

Comment: The least holes you have. the better for the foundation. frost , If it has to stay it can.A better job. ect.